# How to code a method, function or variable in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c

I have just started to learn Objective - C. I have done one year of Java programming and one year of Actionscript. I need to find a website or blog which tells me how to do the basic things for example declare a variable or how to write a method and function. I cant seem to find this anywhere. If someone could give me some good links that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

[Introduction to The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) from Apple would probably be a good place to get started with the Objective-C language.

In general, declaring variables aren't too different within a method.

```
-(void)doSomething {
  // Declaration of a variable.
  int myVariable = 0;
}
```

The syntax for methods and functions can be a little bit different, and the language itself allows the use of C, as Objective-C is a superset of C.

One conceptual difference about classes and objects in Objective-C compared to Java is that the implementation and the declaration is separated into two different files. The "header" information which defines the `interface` is usually included in the `.h` file, while the `implementation` is included in the `.m` file.

The `interface` defines the methods, properties and such, while the `implementation` includes the actual code to use in the methods.

Also, strictly speaking, in Objective-C are not "methods" are not "called", but "messages" are "sent" to objects, and the objects react to them:

```
// The following is sending the "doSomething" message to "myObject".
// Strictly speaking, it's not a method call, but a messaging of an object.
[myObject doSomething];
```

Also, the [Wikipedia article on Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) also gives a pretty good overview of the language as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the book [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157) by Stephen Kochan.

I used the older version when I was learning Objective-C and still reference it on occasion. It is an excellent introduction to the basics of the language.

Comment: Totally agree. This is one of the most well-written technical books I've ever read. It also does not assume you know C, which many Objective-C books do. It will teach you all you need to know about Objective-C, as well as the bits of plain C you need to know and none of the bits you don't.